# How do you create a method that awaits an onRendered event from another template?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I am using an ionic framework package, and I have a sidebar class. There is a class called `ionSideMenu.snapper`, which, looking at the source code, is defined when the `ionSideMenuContainer` template is rendered, so I get around that by doing the following:

```
import {Template} from "meteor/templating";
import {ReactiveField} from "meteor/peerlibrary:reactive-field";

export const Snapper = new ReactiveField(false);

// now when the side menu is rendered, `IonSideMenu.snapper` should be defined.
Template['ionSideMenuContainer'].onRendered(() => Snapper(IonSideMenu.snapper));
```

However, I want to create a static method on my `Sidebar` class that will await for the `Snapper` to be defined, then will run the `disabled` function.

```
export class Sidebar extends BlazeComponent {
  static disable() {
    // await the snapper to be defined
    Snapper().disable();
  }
}
```

How could this awaiting function be done, such that I could call it from any other template and it will disable when it is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Believe I have found an answer. Posting it if anyone needs it.

```
import {Tracker} from "meteor/tracker";

// ...
class Sidebar extends BlazeComponent {
  static _awaitSnapperReady(callback) {
    Tracker.autorun(c => {
      const snapper = Snapper();
      if (snapper) {
        callback(snapper);
        c.stop();  // end the current computation.
      }
    });
  }
  static disable() {
    Sidebar._awaitSnapperReady(snapper => snapper.disable());
  }
}
```